# Rearrange/sort data in form of associate array with Alphabet index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of records (some category titles fetched from a database table) I want to sort them in following format so I can achieve something like [this](http://envato.megadrupal.com/html/couponday/light/brand-list.html)

```
$categories = array(
'A' => array(       
            'Abreva',
            'Activia',
            'Advantage',
            'Advil',
            'Air Wick',
            'Ajax',
            'Aleve'),
'B' => array(),
```

... and so on upto Z
);

I don't know how to perform this but to the best of my knowledge It should be some sort of sorting function performed after fetching all the data from database. I have tried on my own but unable to achieve the desired output. Any help/hint would be sufficient. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not tell the database engine to sort it?

Comment: @JonathanGray And how can we tell the database engine? I assume using some MySQL query but I don't have any knowledge regarding that... Can you tell me some hint/sample?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name

Comment: @JonathanGray Well this will return an array of all the category titles sorted alphabetically (Which I have done so far)... My question is How to divide them regarding first alphabet and having an array of arrays as I have mentioned above...

Comment: You can loop through the sorted array looking at the first character in each entry. Then you can use that to create associative arrays. I'm on my phone or i would code up an example for you.

Comment: @JonathanGray thanks friend... I would give it a try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go...

```
<?php
$categories=array(); $i=0;
$a=array('fas','abas','ajuma','bizzo','bike','Chacha','cade'); //array, i assume as a data from db

foreach($a as $key=>$value){ // loop array $a as a result from db
if( substr(ucfirst($value),0,1) == 'A'){ 
 //array_push($categories["A"],$value);  // array_push seems not to work 
$categories["A"][]=$value;
 }
if( substr(ucfirst($value),0,1) == 'B'){
 $categories['B'][]=$value;
 }
if( substr(ucfirst($value),0,1) == 'C'){
 $categories['C'][]=$value;
  }
  // .. for C,D ....Z
}
 print_r($categories); //print result
 ?>
```

You can copy and see results

Comment: You're using substr unneccessarily, calling it too many times, and those multiple if statements aren't needed. That code is not only inefficient, but is also (no offense) quite ugly and would be hard to maintain. -1

Answer (score 1):

This should be much more efficient:

```
$sorted = array();
$unsorted = array('Abreva', 'Activia', 'Advantage', 'Advil', 'Ball Park', 'Band-Aid', 'Banquet', 'Barilla', 'Campbells', 'Capri Sun', 'Carefree', 'Caress', 'Dannon', 'Dawn', 'Degree', 'Del Monte', 'Eldership', 'Eldest', 'Xlectre', 'Electrical', 'Facetious', 'Facetiously', 'Facetiousness', 'Facile', 'Gabbler', 'Gabel', 'Gabion', 'Gable', 'Habitableness', 'Habitance', 'Zabitant', 'Habitation', 'Habitator', 'Habitual', '1st Class', '7th Sky');
sort($unsorted);
foreach($unsorted as $item){ // loop array $unsorted as a result from db
    $startchr = ucfirst($item[0]);
    $sorted[is_numeric($startchr)?'0-9':$startchr][] = $item;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sorted); //print sorted
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of above comments and answer I have successfully solved the issue thanks @fasM and @JonathanGray

Following is the exact php code

```
$sorted = array();
$unsorted = array('Abreva', 'Activia', 'Advantage', 'Advil', 'Ball Park', 'Band-Aid', 'Banquet', 'Barilla', 'Campbells', 'Capri Sun', 'Carefree', 'Caress', 'Dannon', 'Dawn', 'Degree', 'Del Monte', 'Eldership', 'Eldest', 'Xlectre', 'Electrical', 'Facetious', 'Facetiously', 'Facetiousness', 'Facile', 'Gabbler', 'Gabel', 'Gabion', 'Gable', 'Habitableness', 'Habitance', 'Zabitant', 'Habitation', 'Habitator', 'Habitual', '1st Class', '7th Sky');
sort($unsorted);
$alphabets = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');
foreach($unsorted as $item){ // loop array $unsorted as a result from db
    $inserted = false;
    foreach($alphabets as $alphabet){
        if(substr(ucfirst($item),0,1) == $alphabet){ 
            $sorted[$alphabet][] = $item;
            $inserted = true;
        }
    }
    if($inserted == false){
        $sorted['0-9'][] = $item;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sorted); //print sorted
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Not bad, given what you were told. But please check my answer :)